# Angularjs dynamically show / hide an element based on a variable stored in session storage and stored on $scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have been searching a lot and can't find a solution to that will show / hide the element without refreshing the page. This is a simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish:

HTML:

```
<input ng-show="user == null" type="text" placeholder="username" ng-model="username" />
<button ng-show="user == null" ng-click="login()">Add User</button>
<div ng-show="user != null"> should show when user is defined </div>
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.login = function () {
   sessionStorage.setItem('username', $scope.username);
   $scope.user = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
 };
```

I am able to successfully get the username stored in session storage, but I cannot get the input to disappear and the div to appear dynamically after the variable is stored in sessionStorage and the $scope.user.

The show and hide do work if I refresh the page after logging in.

The other approach is the show/hide the elements in the login function, but I can't figure out how to do that either.

Is there a way to get these to dynamically show/hide?

Comment: Can you provide codepen snippet or jsfiddle code snippet?

Comment: @PareshGami I will work on it now

Comment: Yes please provide same so i can help you

Comment: there is nothing obviously wrong with this code;  `ng-show` should be updating dynamically, unless your `user` variable is in a different scope;  For what it's worth, that is definitely possible when working with primitives rather than objects, but it's not clear if that is happening in your case without seeing more of the HTML and controller structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code provided. Here's an example that works perfectly, the only thing I removed was the access to `sessionStorage` because it's not allowed to be used in sandbox mode for security reasons.

Make sure you have declared the `ng-app` and `ng-controller` directives respectively

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.login = function() {
      $scope.user = $scope.username;
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <input ng-show="user == null" type="text" placeholder="username" ng-model="username" />
  <button ng-show="user == null" ng-click="login()">Add User</button>
  <div ng-show="user != null">should show when user is defined</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code was helpful, I'm not sure what fixed it, but something did